# generate 2d triangular mesh opencv

Tags: python, opencv, 2d, mesh, triangular

Is it possible generate a 2D triangular mesh using opencv python?
My ultimate goal is obtain a binary image with the mesh drawn in order to use this "new image" as a mask layer.

I have this image:
[image: image description]

I want to generate something like this:
[image: image description]

This image above is a plot with matplotlib of a possible mesh for the first image.
I'm using different modules to generate the mesh, and one of my problens is this mesh (on the plot is 3D) and I want to have a 2D mesh.
I want to keep all the images with the same size, so I think it i wise use only 1 module, like opencv.

Thanks

Comment: An 89MB 24bit `.BMP` file (containing only black and white colours) embedded in the question? Is that some sort of a joke? You do realize that a PNG with the same data is about 250kB? Please fix that.

Comment: @DanMašek I'm sorry for the inconvienient. Already changed.